# Size (width, height) of an image loaded over http

Tags: image, http, header, metadata

Is there a way to know the size (w,h) of an image loaded over http with the headers or metadata (before having downloaded all of it) ?

Comment: Do you use any programming lanugage on the server?

Comment: I'm loading the picture from Facebook actually. Like http://graph.facebook.com/pierrevalade/picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, this not possible, except you pass this information by yourself to the HTTP headers.

Comment: You can add whatever header you want. The common prefix for indiviual header is to prepend a 'X-' to it, like 'X-ImageHeight'.